# How to reflect updates in a loop?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a migration run. At each iteration i can update several rows. But how can i skip already updated rows? Changes inside the loop are not visible to the outside (yes I know - stable result) - but how can i change that? I want, that if a person already has a graph_id --> SKIP

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS persons_2_persons, persons, graph;

CREATE TABLE graph (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE persons (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, graph_id INTEGER REFERENCES graph(id));
CREATE TABLE persons_2_persons("from" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES persons(id), "to" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES persons(id));

INSERT INTO persons (graph_id) VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);

INSERT INTO persons_2_persons VALUES
(1,2),(2,1),
(2,3),(3,2);

-- Table has about 18 Mio records. 30-40 persons are connected --> goal: give each graph/cluster an graph_id
-- I also tried with CURSORs

DO $x$
DECLARE  
  var_record RECORD;
  var_graph_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    
    FOR var_record IN SELECT * FROM persons -- Reevaluate after each iteration
    LOOP
        IF var_record.graph_id IS NULL THEN -- this should be false at the 2nd and 3nd iteration because we updated the data in 1st iteration
          INSERT INTO graph DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id INTO var_graph_id;
          RAISE NOTICE '%', var_graph_id;
        
          UPDATE persons SET graph_id = var_graph_id WHERE id IN (1,2,3); -- (1,2,3) is found by a RECURESIVE CTE. This are normally 30-40 persons
         
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$x$;

SELECT * FROM persons;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the first command in the loop refresh that individual record:

```
select * from persons into var_record where id=var_record.id;
```

Comment: Ok - i thought there is maybe a better / optimized solution. But ok ;-) Thx

Comment: It would probably make sense for the FOR loop to just select the primary key rather than the whole record, and then populate the record (rather than over write it) in the first statement inside the loop.  But I figure the fewer changes made to existing code, the less likelihood of introducing a new bug.

Comment: Yes - I did it with PK because it can use the index then (as far as I saw). But: Making lots of small SELECTs is also not good - anyhow - it will just run once - should be ok ;-)